# How do I simplify a radical within a radical in this half-angle problem?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I don't understand how to simplify the following radicals and arrive at the final answer below. I can make it to this point:

$$\sin\left(-\frac{3\pi}{8}\right)=\pm\sqrt{1+\frac{\sqrt2}{2}\over2}$$

However the final answer is:

$$\sin\left(-\frac{3\pi}{8}\right)=-\frac{\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}}{2}$$

I've filled a couple pages and tried finding a good answer on how to do this simplification, but without success. Any help is gratefully received!

edit: removed the square over the denominator 2 in the final answer.

Comment: Are you very sure that this is supposed to be the correct answer?
Unless I'm missing something profound I don't think that those two are equal...

Comment: I made a mistake: the 2 in the answer's denominator should not be squared. Thank you for pointing that out!

Comment: No problem, happy to help! :)
So can you edit your original post to correct for this mistake please, so that we see what it should be.
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, $\;-\frac\pi2<-\frac{3\pi}8< 0\;$ , so we're in the fourth quadrant and thus sine is negative here. Second:

$$\sqrt{\frac{1+\frac{\sqrt2}{2}}{2}}=\sqrt{\frac{\frac{2+\sqrt2}2}{2}}=\sqrt{\frac{2+\sqrt2}4}=\frac{\sqrt{2+\sqrt2}}2$$

Comment: Thank you for such a clear explanation! It appears I was trying to rationalize the denominator at your 2nd step, when I should have multiplied the complex fraction (or the numerator) under the radical by $\frac{1}{2}$ and then taken the square root of 4 in the denominator to simplify.

Comment: Correction: I was supposed to multiply $\sqrt{\frac{2+\sqrt{2}}{2}\over{2}}$ by 2 in the numerator and denominator to eliminate the complex fraction, giving me a new denominator of 4.